# BrowserSync injection reload

Tags: gulp

My browser tab don't reload after i save my SASS in visual studio, the compilation goes very well and the file it self http://localhost:3000/css/my-ui.css looks updated

```
function browserSync(done) {
    browsersync.init({
      server: {
        baseDir: "./"
      },
      port: 3000,
     // startPath: './index.html'
      startPath: './css/my-ui.css'
    });
    done();
  }

// BrowserSync reload

function browserSyncReload(done) {
    browsersync.reload();
    done();
  }

// Watching the changes on files

function watchFiles() {
    gulp.watch("./**/*.css", browserSyncReload);
    gulp.watch("./**/*.html", browserSyncReload);
    gulp.watch('./scss/',style);
  }
  

// Defining the tasks
const vendor = gulp.series(clean);
const build = gulp.series(vendor);
const watch = gulp.series(build ,gulp.parallel(watchFiles, browserSync,style));
```

And then with an Chrome extension i am injecting the generated file into my website. I have to this procedure because i don't have access to the website it self. I have to do the CSS outside and in the end of the day send it to the site owner. Kind outdated but it works...

```
// SCSS to CSS compilator
```

function style(){

```
// 1. Define the input file (scss)
return gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')

// 2. Pass it through sass compiler with map
.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
.pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))

// 3. Add auto prefixes
.pipe(autoprefixer({
    browserslistrc: ['last 3 versions', 'ie >= 10', '> 5%'],
    cascade: false
  })
)

// 4. Save the compiled CSS
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
.pipe(
  gulp.dest('./css')
)
```

}

It it because it's an CSS file instead an HTML or PHP file?

Can someone help me?

Comment: You should show your `style` task as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark, i have updated the first post.